# Android Studio Sdk Update fails

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sdk-manager

recently the sdk downloader of android fails downloading a lot of components with this error

```
2020-03-07 15:12:43,179 [  45685]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Install ARM EABI v7a System Image (revision: 6)". 
2020-03-07 15:12:43,181 [  45687]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/armeabi-v7a-23_r06.zip 
2020-03-07 15:12:43,264 [  45770]   WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - An error occurred while preparing SDK package ARM EABI v7a System Image: Request failed with status code 416. 
com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$HttpStatusException: Request failed with status code 416. Status=416, Url=https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/armeabi-v7a-23_r06.zip
```

Does anybody know why? When I try to download the files manually it works

Thanks in advance

Comment: Recently? When did this start?
Never had a problem with it myself.
I assume you already tried with the usual restart of AS? Clearing of cache should be to no avail, but might as well try.
If not, clean install of AS will most likely do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the .android studio named file and try again it will automatically setup all the SDK again with automatic update.

You can find this file in Users->.android studio delete this file and open android studio exe file .As these files are the part of SDK so you can download them they can work but it's sometime creates a issue of dependencies version mismatching So follow the above step to get your SDK updated.